freeing allocated memory returned from function in c++
I have a question that i cant find the answer.
If I have a function like this:
char* f1(char ch, int len) { 
    char* s1=new char[len+1); 
    for(int i; i<len; i++) s1[i]=ch; 
    s1[len]=0; 
}

and I call it like this:
char* str;
str=f1("A", 10);
std:cout << "Something " << str << std::endl;
delete[] str;

everything is ok, but if i want to use it shorter like this:
std:cout << "Something " << f1("A", 10) << std::endl;

I'll end up with allocated memory i cant free.
keeping in mind that memory leaks arent good and should be avoided - is there a way to do this right way?
Tried to search internet with no result.
Considered creating list of pointers that were allocated from the function and free them somewhere later, but its not best/safe way as it is easy to mess.

Use std::string instead of a raw C array.

Your function f1 is declared to return a char * but has no return statement.  That's undefined behaviour.

Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. The snippets you show have plenty of problems, unrelated to your actual question.

A smart pointer could be an option but std::string is a better one.

Also "A" is not a char. You need to use 'A' when you call f1 (as the argument for ch).

BTW - std::string already has a constructor that accepts a length (of type size_t) and a char and creates a string exactly like you attempt with your f1, so you can simply use: std::cout << "Something " << std::string('A', 10) << std::endl;.

Please don't do that NEVER return a pointer to something you have new-ed inside a function. At least return a std::unique_ptr.  But for strings just return a std::string and avoid raw character pointers as arguments too . E.g. write this  std::string f1(std::string_view sv). Looks like somebody has failed to teach you (current) C++ and still used the "C" apporach.

Enable your compiler warnings.  Your compiler could have told you what you've done wrong.

Rule of thumb: Allocation of resources only in constructors. Any class with such allocation in the constructor should de-allocate that resource in the destructor. Avoid new, use the features of <memory> instead.

@RifFox you should not edit your question to invalidate existing answer(s). You should also not edit it to include solutions - this is what the answers are for (you can also post your own answer). This is why I rolled back your last edit. If you want to ask a different question about memory and arrays please post a new question.

You can use a std::unique_ptr like this:
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::unique_ptr<char[]> MyPtr;

MyPtr f1(char ch, int len) {
    MyPtr s1(new char[len+1]);
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) s1[i]=ch;
    s1[len]=0;
    return s1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Something " << f1('A', 10).get() << std::endl;
}

Background: the object returned from f1 gets destroyed at the end of the statement -- that is, after executing the line, when the ; is reached.
Btw, I had to fix various minor typos in your code; in the future, just copy-paste your code into the question, instead of retyping it...
Of course, at the end of the day, you should just be using std::string -- you are, after all, using C++...
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Something " << std::string(10, 'A') << std::endl;
}


It is just example concept of a problem and it is not about strings and text but arrays and memory. I think it will be best to use "typedef std::unique_ptr<char[]> MyPtr;", will try it.

Well, if it's about arrays then std::vector is usually the way to go. std::array exists, but it has limited use since it's fixed size.
Again, there are few situations where the old C shenanigans are appropriate in C++.

There are several issues in your code:

f1 is supposed to return a char* but does not contain a return statement (like return s1;).

You call f1 with f1("A", 10). But the first parameter is supposed to be a char and "A" isn't. It should be f1('A', 10) instead.

In C++ it not not recommended to use raw C arrays. One of the problems with it is the need for manual memory management that you encounter.
It is better to use standard library classes like std::vector (for a general purpose dynamic array), or in this case of an null-terminated array of characters - use std::string
(requires: #include <string>).
These classes will manage the memory automatically for you and you will not have to worry about leaks.

std::string already has a constructor that accepts a length and a character and creates a string like your f1 attempts to do, so you can simply use:
#include <string>
// ...
std::cout << "Something " << std::string(10, 'A') << std::endl;

Output:
Something AAAAAAAAAA

Live demo
If you need your f1 to do some additional things as well, you can still create a std::string in it (like above) and return it.


